# Closed form for $\int_0^1 t^n \log(t^4-t^2+1) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral:
$$I(n)=\int_0^1 t^n \log(t^4-t^2+1) dt$$
The motivation is that, for odd values of $n$, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C7%5Dlog%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C4%5D-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) suggests beautiful closed forms, but I can't see the pattern. For even values of $n$ it does find closed forms, but not always.

Therefore I want to see if there is a general closed form for the general case, that could explain this even-odd disparity.

By integrating by parts, I got the following integral:
$$I(n)=-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}(4t^3-2t)}{t^4-t^2+1}dt$$
From here, doing partial fractions with the four roots of the denominator, $+e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$, $-e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$, $+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{6}}$, $-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{6}}$, we get four integrals of the form $$\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}(4t^3-2t)}{t+a}dt$$
But from here? How to proceed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write $t^4-t^2+1=(1/4)(4t^4-4t^2+4)=(1/4)(4t^4-4t^2+1+3)=(1/4)((2t^2-1)^2+3)=(1/4)(2t^2-1-\sqrt{3})(2t^2-1+\sqrt{3})$ to have only quadratics in the log. You could factor the quadratics to have only linear terms.
The roots are $\pm\sqrt{3}/2\pm i/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the odd case $n=2m+1$
\begin{align}
I_{2m+1}&=\int_0^1 t^{2m+1} \log(t^4-t^2+1) \overset{t^2\to t}{dt}\\
&= \frac12\int_0^1 t^{m} \log(t^2-t+1) {dt}\\
&= \Re \int_0^1 t^{m} \log(t-a) {dt}\>\>\>\>\>(a=e^{i\frac\pi 3})\\
&\overset{ibp}=-\frac1{m+1}\Re\int_0^1 \frac{t^{m+1}}{t-a}dt\\
&= -\frac1{m+1}\Re \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}k a^k(t-a)^{m-k}\ dt\\
&= -\frac1{m+1}\Re \bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m+1}k \frac{a^k (t-a)^{m-k+1}}{m-k+1}+a^k\ln(t-a)\bigg]_0^1\\
&=-\frac2{m+1}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{m-k} \binom{m+1}k}{m-k+1}\sin\frac{\pi(3m+3-2k)}{6}\sin\frac{\pi(m-k+1)}6\\
& \>\>\>\>\> \>\>
+\frac\pi{3(m+1)}\sin\frac{\pi(m+1)}3
\end{align}
which exhibits the pattern $I_{2m+1}= a+b\cdot\frac\pi{\sqrt3}$, with rational numbers $a$ and $b$. In particular
\begin{align}
&I_1=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}-1,\>\>\>
I_3=\frac\pi{4\sqrt3}-\frac12,\>\>\>
I_5=-\frac1{36}\\
&I_7=\frac5{24}-\frac\pi{8\sqrt3},\>\>\>
I_9=\frac{101}{600}-\frac\pi{10\sqrt3},\>\>\>
I_{11}=-\frac7{720}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide some additional details regarding the last steps? I can't see where the $a^k\ln(t-a)$ comes from. @Quanto

Comment: @Zima - The $\ln(t-a)$  results from  the $k=m+1$ term, i.e. $\int_0^1 \frac1{t-a}dt$.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}(4t^3-2t)}{t+a}dt=\frac1a\int_0^1 4t^{n+4} \left(\frac t a+1\right)^{-1}-2t^{n+2}\left(\frac t a+1\right)^{-1}dt$$

Setting $-\frac ta=x,t=-a x$ and using the [incomplete beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/) $\operatorname B_x(a,b)=\int_0^xt^{a-1}(1-t)^bdt:$

$$- \int_0^{-\frac1a}4(-a)^{n+4}x^{n+4}(1-x)^{-1}-2(-a)^{n+2}x^{n+2}(1-x)^{-1}dx$$

to get:

$$-2(-1)^na^{n+2}(2a^2-1)\operatorname B_{-\frac1a}(n+3,0)-\frac{4a}{n+3}+\frac4{n+4}$$

where the [finite sum](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06515.pdf) representation is:

$$-\operatorname B_x(m,0)=\ln(1-x)+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{x^k}k$$

so

$$\boxed{\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}(4t^3-2t)}{t+a}dt =2(-1)^na^{n+2}(2a^2-1)\left(\ln\left(\frac1a+1\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}\frac{(-a^{-1})^k}k\right)-\frac{4a}{n+3}+\frac4{n+4}}$$

Comment: [+1] Very interesting.

Comment: Thank you, now it's just a matter of tedious computations for the four integrals. What I still don't get is why for odd $n$ this results in a beautiful number while for even $n$ it does not.

Answer (score 2):

**Closed-Form for odd case**

Letting $t^2\mapsto t$ reduces the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{2m+1} & =\int_0^1 t^{2 m+1} \ln \left(t^4-t^2+1\right) d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 t^m \ln \left(t^2-t+1\right) d t 
\end{aligned}
$$
Using $\ln \left(a^2+b^2\right)=2 \Re(\ln (a+bi))$, we rewrite the integral as
$$
I_{2m+1}=\Re \int_0^1 t^m \ln \left(\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i\right) d t =\Re \int_0^1 t^m \ln (t-a) d t
$$
where $a=e^\frac{\pi i}{3}.$

Using integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 t^m \ln (t-a) d t
& =\frac{1}{m+1}\left[t^{m+1} \ln (t-a)\right]_0^1-\frac{1}{m+1} \int_0^1 \frac{t^{m+1}}{t-a} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{m+1} \ln (1-a)-\frac{1}{m+1} \int_0^1 \frac{t^{m+1}}{t-a} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{m+1} \ln (e^{\frac {-i\pi}{3}})-\frac{1}{m+1} \int_0^1\left(\frac{t^{m+1}-a^{m+1}}{t-a}+\frac{a^{m+1}}{t-a}\right) d t \\
& =\frac{-i\pi}{3(m+1)} -\frac{1}{m+1} \left[\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^m t^k a^{m-k} d t+\frac{a^{m+1}}{m+1}[\ln (t-a)]_0^1 \right] \\
\Re \int_0^1 t^m \ln (t-a) d t
& =-\frac{1}{m+1}\left( \Re \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{a^{m-k}}{k+1} +\Re\left[a^{m+1}(\ln (1-a)-\ln (-a))\right] \right)\\&=-\frac{1}{m+1}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{3}(m-k)\right)}{k+1}- \frac{ \pi}{3} \sin \frac{(m+1) \pi}{3}\right]\\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that
$$\boxed{I_{2m+1}=-\frac{1}{m+1}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{3}(m-k)\right)}{k+1}- \frac{ \pi}{3} \sin \frac{(m+1) \pi}{3}\right]}$$

---

For examples,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I_1=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}-1; \qquad  I_3=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{3}}; \qquad  I_5=-\frac{1}{36} \\
& I_7=\frac{5}{24}-\frac{\pi}{8 \sqrt{3}}; \quad  I_9=\frac{101}{600}-\frac{\pi}{10 \sqrt{3}}; \quad I_{11}=-\frac{7}{720}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you @Lai

Comment: Glad to know that you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the factorization of the logarithm
$$\int t^n \log(t-a)\,dt=\frac{t^{n+2} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+2;n+3;\frac{t}{a}\right)}{a (n+1)   (n+2)}+\frac{t^{n+1} \log (t-a)}{n+1}$$ Since $a$ is a complex
$$\int t^n \log(t-a)\,dt=\frac{a^{n+1} B_{\frac{1}{a}}(n+2,0)+\log (1-a)}{n+1}$$ Recombining the four terms and going from the incomplete beta function to the Gaussian hypergeometric functions
$$(n+1)(n+3)I(n)= \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+3}{2};\frac{n+5}{2};\frac{1-i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+$$ $$\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+3}{2};\frac{n+5}{2};\frac{1+i
   \sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$$ which explains the difference of the results for different parities of $n$.

For even values of $n$, the results are not so bad
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2n & I_{2n} \\
 0 & -4+\frac{\pi }{2}+\sqrt{3} \log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \\
 2 & \frac{1}{9} (3 \pi -10) \\
 4 & \frac{8}{75}+\frac{\pi }{10}-\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{3} \log
   \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \\
 6 & \frac{388}{735}-\frac{\pi }{14}-\frac{1}{7} \sqrt{3} \log
   \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \\
 8 & \frac{946}{2835}-\frac{\pi }{9} \\
 10 & -\frac{2888}{38115}-\frac{\pi }{22}+\frac{1}{11} \sqrt{3}
   \log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \\
 12 & -\frac{178492}{585585}+\frac{\pi }{26}+\frac{1}{13}
   \sqrt{3} \log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Consider for the even case
$$J_{n}=\, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{3}{2};n+\frac{5}{2};a\right)$$
$$J_n=\frac {2n+3}{a^{n+2}}\left(\sqrt{a} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac {a^k}{2k-1 } \right)$$
Consider for the odd case
$$K_{n}=\, _2F_1(1,n+2;n+3;a)$$
$$K_n=-\frac {n+2}{a^{n+2}}\left(\log(1-a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{a^k} k\right)$$

Now, the problem is that $a$ is a complex number (then a lot of simplifications are required).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please clarify why the Gaussian Hypergeometric function explains the difference between even and odd values of $n$? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Also, how did you get all the results you found for $I_{2n}$? I am curious, maybe is there a way to simplify the hypergeometric function?

Comment: @Zima. Did you notice the $2$ in denominator of the second and third arguments ? For $I_{2n}$ have been required a lot of simplifications of complex numbers.